Is CallerMemberNameAttribute guaranteed to be evaluated before inlining?
Here is the documentation for the attribute. It does not mention when it is evaluated.
Here is the documentation for the greater 'CallerInformation' mechanism. It makes the following assertion:

Caller info values are emitted as literals into the Intermediate Language (IL) at compile time. Unlike the results of the StackTrace property for exceptions, the results aren't affected by obfuscation.

but does not contain any statements as to timing, sequence or explicitly inlining.
Is CallerMemberNameAttribute guaranteed to be set before that caller is inlined?
If not, does a more robust mechanism exist by now?
(I actually want the signature or at least name of the current function, but all instructions to accomplish that go towards "call another function and there use CallerMemberNameAttribute" or to obvious runtime solutions. Not thrilled about the prospect of having to annotate every caller with [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]: It is easy to miss in Code Review and not at all(?) supported by Refactoring tools.)

What problem do you need to solve? Through all that text, I get that you want the name -- or better if possible the complete signature -- of the current method, without resorting to runtime-reflection? Could you give an example of code that would suffer from inlining as anticipated by yourself?

@Fildor: Functions call A => B => C. C has CallerMemberNameAttribute. B gets inlined. Debug output: B; Release output: A. Problem! In C++ I'd just pass to C in B: __func__.

But that's just not how inlining works in C#.

@Charlieface : That could have been an answer. Thence the [tag:language-lawyer] tag. ... Currently the one present answer is (yet?) a bit short on references, so you still have your chance.

Inlining is not something the C# compiler does, it happens at a lower level in the JIT (or AOT compiler), so the C# compiler will always emit the value in a normal ldstr and callvirt instruction. In any case, inlining is never allowed to have side-effects, so even if it was inlined it shouldn't have been an issue.
You can prove this with a simple test that uses MethodImpl.AggressiveInlining, see the results and the decompilation.
Note also the spec which says:

21.5.5.4 The CallerMemberName attribute
The System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberNameAttribute is allowed on optional parameters when there is a standard implicit conversion (§10.4.2) from string to the parameter’s type.
If a function invocation from a location within the body of a function member or within an attribute applied to the function member itself or its return type, parameters or type parameters in source code omits an optional parameter with the CallerMemberNameAttribute, then a string literal representing the
name of that member is used as an argument to the invocation instead of the default parameter value.

So the spec explicitly states that it has to use that value as the parameter, no inlining is allowed.

The emphasis might work better, if reduced to just "that" or "that member", that is, unlike my original quote it rules out explicitly whathever other member might be there if that step happened after some hypothetical transformation. This wording ought to require the correct value to be placed and thereby forbid future developments in that regard (unless changed, of course, but we have to choose our axioms somewhere), as desired.

"Compile Time" is unfortunately a bit ambiguous in c#, since there is both a c# -> IL compiler, and a IL -> machine code compiler (called just-in-time-compiler, or jitter). There is also an Ahead of Time compiler, but that essentially does the same thing as the jitter, just "Ahead of time".
Your quote makes it clear that caller information is generated as part of the C# -> IL compilation.
Inlining on the other hand is the responsibility of the jitter (or AOT). So yes, it is guaranteed to be evaluated before any inlining.

Well, if you say that it "makes it clear"... - Cannot say it did for me. But good news either way.

I think Jonas was referring to "Caller info values are emitted as literals into the Intermediate Language (IL) at compile time." (the bold part in partticular). And I must agree, that's pretty clear.

@Fildor: That only helps when knowing whether inlining is not allowed to happen before said emittance. Note that the sentence does not become even slightly wrong, if for call A => B => C, B were inlined before emitting the literal into the IL of C. Exactly the same thing would still happen - just with the wrong value (A instead of B). Also note that "Currently no compiler does it that way." is basically relying on undefined behaviour and may change at any minor version increase of said compiler if there is no guarantee in the spec.

@Zsar I think it is simply that the documentation presumes some familiarity with the .net architecture. C# is also fairly good at avoiding "undefined behavior", see the "pit of success" design goal.

I accepted the other answer, as it satisfies the [tag:language-lawyer] with a spec citation, but this one was first and gave me actionable advice almost immediately, which is also nice. So +1 at least.
